# unit normal vector to paraboloid surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a question about unit normal vectors the the surface of the elliptic paraboloid described by $z =2x^2 + y^2$ at the point $(1,1,3)$.

The answer I get is $\dfrac{4\mathbf{i} + 2\mathbf{j} - \mathbf{k}}{\sqrt{21}}$

However, the back of the book says it is:

$\dfrac{-4\mathbf{i} - 2\mathbf{j} + \mathbf{k}}{\sqrt{21}}$

Where is this extra minus sign coming from?

Comment: Did you know if your vector is outer or inner?

Comment: The whole question says: Recall that if f(x,y,z) = c describes a surface, then divergence of f is normal to the surface. Find the unit normal vector to the surface of the elliptic paraboloid described by z = 2x^2 + y^2 at the point (1,1,3)

Comment: Do you mean "gradient" instead divergence?

Comment: yes, sorry. It looks like an upside down triangle

Comment: @DiegoMath Can you deduce my mistake?

Comment: Try $F(x,y,z)=z-2x^2-y^2$. Note that $G=-F$ satisfy your requeriment, but in this case the orientation of the surface is other.

Comment: @DiegoMath Why would I change it to that?

Comment: Look this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)